# CLI 'Rails s' command not working, localhost refused to connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, bundle

Tried to run Rails s command on Rails shell but it would not let me do it and it stops at use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to stop and stays there for ages and doesn't get executed. I have to Ctrl-C of which allows me to exit.

When I try to connect to my localhost it says the host refused to connect. Any ideas?

CLI picture:
[image: CLI picture]

Comment: What do you mean by it won't let you run `rails s`? It looks like the server started

Comment: Are you using http://localhost:3000 to connect via your browser? The output in your screenshot looks normal (you have a few notes about SIG not being implemented but I think that's probably normal because you're on windows)

Comment: @lesonBlooms - unfortunately, I can't help you with your particular problem. but i can provide you with some advice (i'm not an expert on this btw) if you're trying to run ruby on rails, on Windows, it's going to be an uphill battle. I'd suggest you consider a Mac or a linux based distro (e.g. Ubuntu) to experiment with rails.